# regex `match` returns different results based on order of lookup list

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm confused by Javascript's `.match` regex function.

Given string:

```
var a = "today, I will ski with skis";
```

I want to match "today", "ski", and "skis"

```
a.match(/hello|today|skis|trip|ski/g);
```

**Output: ["today", "ski", "skis"]**

The output matches my expectations.

However, if I put "ski" before "skis" in the lookup, it stops at "ski" for both "ski" and "skis" matches:

```
a.match(/hello|today|ski|trip|skis/g);
```

**Output: ["today", "ski", "ski"]**

Why won't it return both "ski" and "skis" and how do I fix it?

---

**EDIT**: to clarify, I'm looking for a dynamic solution to continue searching the list after the first set of characters is already identified. My goal is to dynamically populate the list of search terms and I can't be sure which characters to apply `?` to.

I.e., using `?` operator for `skis?` is not dynamic since I'd have to manually add it for each possible character. If "skittles" or "ski mountain" came after "ski" these would both be ignored by `match`. `ski(.*)` gets closer but it returns everything after its bounding `|` group.

Comment: If you are asking why it doesn't return both "ski" and "skis" for the last "skis" in the input, it's because they are overlapping matches

Comment: There's many strings that are prefixes or otherwise substrings of other words. `var a = "today, I will ski with skittles";`  ---> `a.match(/hello|today|ski|trip|skittles/g);` returns `["today", "ski", "ski"]`. Is that really how the function works?

Comment: Yes regex is greedy, once it finds a match it will continue on the rest without evaluating the other options in your `(...|...|...)`

Comment: Thanks @Emma that's clear. It's a bit tricky to dynamically create a list of search terms with the `?` operator when `.match` stops at the first match (especially in the case of words, like "skittles", that have search terms before it contains, like "ski").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dynamically creating a list of search terms you can make use of the fact that an alternation stops at the first match (see the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)):

> "`x|y` Matches "x", or "y" (if there is no match for "x")

and sort your list of search terms in reverse order (so that, for example, `skis` comes before `ski`) before joining them to make an alternation to search against:

```js
var a = "today, I will learn to heliski with skis at the big mountain";
var search = ['hello', 'today', 'ski', 'trip', 'skis', 'big mountain'];

var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + search.sort().reverse().join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b', 'g');
console.log(a.match(regex));
```

Comment: This is such a clever solution! Is it _always_ the case that `sort` and then `reverse` will result in an ordering that places the offending substring _after_ the other string?

Comment: That's this. 

Comment: `sort` will always sort a substring ahead of a full string i.e. `ski` before `skittles` or `skis` so using `.reverse()` ensures that the longer strings come first.

Comment: @Growler I've improved the regex so that it checks for word boundaries so that `ski` won't match `heliski`. Also added a two word phrase to the search terms.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to match "today", "ski", and "skis"

You can use this pattern: `/today|skis?/g`

In this case, `s?` means: `s` character is an optional, it can be matched zero or one time.

```js
var a = "today, I will ski with skis";
var b = "today, I will ski with ski skis";
var c = "I learned to ski at the ski mountain";

var pattern = /today|skis?/g;

console.log(a.match(pattern));
console.log(b.match(pattern));
console.log(c.match(pattern));
```

---

Update:

If you want to match some word which starts with `ski`, you can use this regex: `/ski\w*/g`

```js
var a = "I learned to ski at the ski mountain";
var b = "This is a word: skittles...";

var pattern = /ski\w*/g;

console.log(a.match(pattern));
console.log(b.match(pattern));
```

Comment: It's a bit tricky to dynamically create a list of search terms with the `?` operator when `.match` stops at the first match (especially in the case of words, like "skittles", that have search terms before it contains, like "ski").

Comment: This works for a single character but is not a dynamic solution. What about several characters after ski (like "skittles") or two words (like "ski mountain")? `var a = "I learned to ski at the ski mountain";` I tried `(.*)` to match any character after "ski": `a.match(/(learned|ski(.*)|at)/g);` but this resulted in `["learned", "ski at the ski mountain"]`

Comment: @Growler I've updated my answer with some word like `skittles`. But I don't understand what's wrong with `ski mountain`?